# How to insert text infront of and after a value in a column, for every value in that column?

Tags: sql, wordpress, append

I have a table with meta values for posts in **wordpress**, the table is called `wp_postmeta`

This table has two important columns called `meta_key` and `meta_value`

One of the Meta Key's are `website` and the corresponding values are a url
                   *(Example www.accentweb.ca)*

What I would like to do is take that value and create a link to it with it's own value as the link:

That is  `www.accentweb.ca`  into

`<a href="http://www.accentweb.ca" target="_blank">www.accentweb.ca</a>`

What would I use for an **sql command**, I have been working on this using set value and a few others but cannot seem to get it to work, idea's?

Comment: ps.  I know I can do this by modifying the PHP in wordpress, however that won't work in this instance due to the size of the table, and how we are moving forward with it (It is built in to add this data when entered in the post custom field)

Comment: What is it you're asking here? *IE www.accentweb.ca would be transformed into www.accentweb.ca*? Create a link where?

Comment: StuckAtWork, Thank you for pointing out the error of my original post, I forgot to wrap the ``` code around it :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET metavalue = '<a href="http://' + meta_value + '" target="_blank">'+meta_value+'</a>'
WHERE meta_key='website'
```

Comment: podiluska I think you are close, however I need to add the HTML around it so that it becomes a link, ex.

www.accentweb.ca becomes `<a href="http://www.accentweb.ca" target="_blank">www.accentweb.ca</a>`  So I think what you have posted is VERY close to what I need.  I should just be able to edit what you have and insert the rest of the code, I will give it a shot right now and let you know, thank you!

Comment: Podiluska - I ended up with a value of 0 in that field for all entries modified.